# HTTPS is working in EC2 server but not from public internet

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, https, port

I have setup HTTPS in my tomcat Windows server. It works fine inside the server via host file setting. I have opened inbound access for 443 port. When I access my site from public internet, I got the below error:
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
The HTTP access from public internet is still working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. It was a Windows firewall setting issue. Initially I saw a inbound rule open for 443 and thought 443 was open. Later by checking the details I found it is open for IIS only not other applications. I added another rule to open 443 for all inbound not limited by application. It solved the problem. I will see if I can refine the 443 rule to only open for tomcat.